# Page numbering with babylonian numerals

Tags: page-numbering

I'm trying to use page numbering with babylonian numerals using Santakku font. The code bellow works only without the `\tableofcontents` command. Using it, the following error happens:

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.1 ...\global \c@workm@mctr \c@page \relax \let }

?
```

I'm using MiKTeX Portable 2.9.6361, updated with the `Update MiKTex` tool.

How to solve this and build a table of contents with the babylonian numerals?

Thanks.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{babyloniannum}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{%
  \ifcase\value{page}%
    0%
  \else
    \ifnum\value{page}>0 %
       \LARGE\babyloniannum{\value{page}}%
    \else
     0%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{My document}\

text

\section{test}\
\newpage
\section{test}\
\newpage
\section{test}\
\newpage
\section{test}\
\newpage
\section{test}\
\newpage
\section{test}\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Where can we find the `babyloniannum` package? And why do you have those `\` after the `\section` macros?

Comment: The babyloniannum package was automatically downloaded when compiling (but it is also here https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babyloniannum). The various \sections is only for testing the table of contents and the \ after them are for making a indented paragraph (in portuguese).

Comment: It is not on TL 2017 however ... And I don't want to download extra fonts for this in order to test

Answer (score 3):

The command is not robust. You should protect it so that it doesn't break on the way to the toc:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{babyloniannum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{%
  \ifcase\value{page}%
    0%
  \else
    \ifnum\value{page}>0 %
       \protect\Large\protect\babyloniannum{\the\c@page}%
    \else
     0%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{My document}\

text

\section{test}\
\newpage
\section{test}\
\newpage
\section{test}\
\newpage
\section{test}\
\newpage
\section{test}\
\newpage
\section{test}\
\end{document}
```